# What's the difference between defaults and vars in an Ansible role?

Tags: ansible

When creating a new Ansible role, the template creates both a `vars` and a `defaults` directory with an empty `main.yml` file. When defining my role, I can place variable definitions in either of these, and they will be available in my tasks.

What's the difference between putting the definitions into `defaults` and `vars`? What should go into `defaults`, and what should to into `vars`? Does it make sense to use both for the same data?

I know that there's a difference in precedence/priority between the two, but I would like to understand what should go where.

Let's say that my role would create a list of directories on the target system. I would like to provide a list of default directories to be created, but would like to allow the user to override them when using the role.

Here's what this would look like:

```
---
- directories:
  - foo
  - bar
  - baz
```

I could place this either into the `defaults/main.yml` or in the `vars/main.yml`, from an execution perspective, it wouldn't make any difference - but where should it go?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The Ansible documentation on [variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) summarizes this nicely:

> If multiple variables of the same name are defined in different places, they win in a certain order, which is:
>
> - extra vars (-e in the command line) always win
> - then comes connection variables defined in inventory (ansible_ssh_user, etc)
> - then comes "most everything else" (command line switches, vars in play, included vars, role vars, etc)
> - then comes the rest of the variables defined in inventory
> - then comes facts discovered about a system
> - then "role defaults", which are the most "defaulty" and lose in priority to everything.

So suppose you have a "tomcat" role that you use to install Tomcat on a bunch of webhosts, but you need different versions of tomcat on a couple hosts, need it to run as different users in other cases, etc.  The `defaults/main.yml` file might look something like this:

```
tomcat_version: 7.0.56
tomcat_user: tomcat
```

Since those are just default values it means they'll be used if those variables aren't defined anywhere else for the host in question. You could override these via extra-vars, via facts in your inventory file, etc. to specify different values for these variables.

Edit: Note that the above list is for Ansible 1.x.  In Ansible 2.x the list has been expanded on.  As always, the [Ansible Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) provides a detailed description of variable precedence for 2.x.

Comment: Thanks, that's an excellent page - that's what I was looking for. I goes into a lot more detail on what to put in `defaults` and what in `vars` further down.

Comment: it's worth emphasizing: **role vars have an evil-high precedence**. in my experience they are higher than play vars, which is really annoying.

Comment: 5 years later, but... I tend to look at it this way: role defaults are things which I expect a user of the role to override in their vars somewhere. Role vars, OTOH, allow me to avoid hard-coding information in a task, but will likely only be overridden for testing, and changed by a role maintainer. As an example, an initial admin username would be in defaults, but dependency versions would be in vars.

Comment: @tedder42 omg, thanks for that comment, was looking for this info. Just run into the issue having my play-level vars being ignored because the var I wanted to override was specified in vars instead of defaults on the role level... I was so confused.

Answer (score 63):

Role variables defined in `var` have a very high precedence - they can only be overwritten by passing them on the command line, in the specific task or in a block. Therefore, almost all your variables should be defined in `defaults`.

In the article "[Variable Precedence - Where To Put Your Role Vars](https://codereviewvideos.com/course/ansible-tutorial/video/variable-precedence-where-to-put-your-role-vars)" the author gives one example of what to put in `vars`: System-specific constants that don't change much. So you can have `vars/debian.yml` and `vars/centos.yml` with the same variable names but different values and include them conditionally.

Comment: IMO, this answer is better than the chosen one because this tells me: `vars.yaml` are only overwritten by cli `-e` declarations, AND gives a great example of when they might be useful. Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 9):

IMHO it is impractical and not sensible that Ansible places such high priority on configuration in **vars** of **roles**. Configuration in `vars/main.yml` and `defaults/main.yml` should be low and probably the same priority.

Are there any real life examples of cases where we want this type of behavior?

There are examples that we dont' want this.

The point to make here is that configuration in `defaults/main.yml` cannot be dynamic. Configuration in `vars/main.yml` can. So for example you can include configuration for specific OS and version dynamically as shown in [geerlingguy.postgresql](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-postgresql)

But because precedence is so strange and impractical in Ansible geerlingguy needs to introduce **pseudo variables** as can be seen in [variables.yml](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-postgresql/blob/master/tasks/variables.yml)

```
- name: Define postgresql_packages.
  set_fact:
    postgresql_packages: "{{ __postgresql_packages | list }}"
  when: postgresql_packages is not defined
```

This is a concrete real life example that demonstrates that the precedence is impractical.

Another point to make here is that we want roles to be configurable. Roles can be external, managed by someone else. As a general rule you don't want configuration in roles to have high priority.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: If they should be the same priority, then they shouldn't both exist.

Comment: I was about to rant myself about this very unclear and impractical way of doing things, then again it is documented :)? I agree, perhaps a proposal can be made towards the developers, then again, it may break a lot for existing installations.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, anything that goes into “role defaults” (the defaults folder inside the role) is the most malleable and easily overridden. Anything in the vars directory of the role overrides previous versions of that variable in namespace. The idea here to follow is that the more explicit you get in scope, the more precedence it takes with command line -e extra vars always winning. Host and/or inventory variables can win over role defaults, but not explicit includes like the vars directory or an include_vars task.
[doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

Answer (score -6):

Variables and defaults walk hand in hand. here's an example

```
-name: install package
 yum: name=xyz{{package_version}} state=present
```

in your defaults file you would have something like:

```
package_version: 123
```

What ansible will do is, it's gonna take the value of `package_version` and put it next to the package name so it will read somewhere as:

```
-name: install package
 yum: name=xyz123 state=present
```

This way it will install `xyz123` and not `xyz123.4` or whatever is in the great repository of xyz's.

At the end it will do `yum install -y xyz123`

So basically the defaults are the values present, if you do not set a specific value for the variables, cause that space can't stay empty.

Comment: Downvoted because it does not address the question. Obviously `defaults` are used when there are no `vars` defined, but the answer does not explain, _why_ you would define a value as one or the other, which is what the OP asked. Compare to the explanation below.